# How to make a spreadsheet formula execute every day

Tags: sql, google-sheets, datediff, google-query-language

I have the following formula which fetches data from the same day from table **UniqueLast**:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(UniqueLast!$A$3:X;"select * where dateDiff(A, now())=0"))
```

It runs correctly but **sometimes** the table where this formula is executed keeps the result from the previuos day which is already old. How can I make a regulation for running the formula in 00:00?

Comment: i do not see the need for the sql and datediff tags

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Maybe because the title and the body doesn't match tightly. As I understand the question is about what sql statement should be used as the parameter of the Google Sheets' QUERY function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro function and include the above expression. Use VBExpress and create a script (.exe) to open the spreadsheet and run the macro. Add it in the Windows scheduled tasks.

Function to call in Macro

```
Function getNextRunTime() As Date
Dim curDate As Date
Dim curTime As Date
Dim chkTime As Date
Dim runTime As Date

curDate = Date
curTime = TimeValue(Now)

runTime = curDate + TimeValue("15:59:00")
chkTime = curDate + curTime

If chkTime > runTime Then 'schedule for next day'

runTime = DateAdd("d", 1, runTime)
End If

getNextRunTime = runTime

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement parameter of the QUERY function should be a single value of type TEXT. NOW() it not valid Google Query Language function. Google Sheets magnes dates on the background as numbers with a different EPOCH date so we should convert it to a date with the proper format. Try

```
=QUERY(
UniqueLast!$A$3:X,
"select * where dateDiff(A, date """&TEXT(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""")=0"
)
```

Removed IFERROR in order to make it easy to check if change proposed works with the OP data. You could add it later once you are sure that it does.